# Testing Flask with Flask-Testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to write my first test for a simple Flask app. I simply want a test that will check if the app is running and gets a 200 response code by querying the root app url '/'.

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND
```

This suggests that the server is running but that the base url can't be found? What's going on?

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from flask import Flask
from flask_testing import LiveServerTestCase

class MyTest(LiveServerTestCase):

  def create_app(self):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    return app

  def test_flask_application_is_up_and_running(self):
    response = urlopen(self.get_server_url())
    self.assertEqual(response.code, 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading the Flask testing docs: You usally don't go through network and HTTP to test your apps. [Instead you create a test client from flask, which you then use to do requests directly to your app.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/testing/#the-first-test)

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go - I also tried following that example on the page you cited, the example I was following used the Flask-Testing module - see Flask-Testing Extension at http://damyanon.net/flask-series-testing/

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use nosetest. It is very old and its development has stopped. Try pytest.

Comment: Thanks - this page cites the same example, https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/ only difference is that it sets a port for the app, tried that too no go. Will have a go with the link you sent later.

Comment: Also the reason I started off with nosetests is because I wanted something supported by Travis CI, their docs mention nosetests or make test only https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/